# jquery slider vertically is not working

Tags: jquery, user-interface

hi i have made a vertical slider using the jquery to slide the text vertically. The text does move up and down when the handle of slider is moved but the handle itself is not moving ... i dont know what is going on out there??

Please somebody help me out!!!

Here is the code:

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#content-slider").slider({
    animate: true,
        orientation: "vertical",
        value: 100,
    change: handleSliderChange,
    slide: handleSliderSlide
  });

});

function handleSliderChange(e, ui)
{
  var maxScroll = $("#content-scroll").attr("scrollHeight") - $
("#content-scroll").height();
  $("#content-scroll").animate({scrollTop: ui.value * (maxScroll /
100) }, 1000);

}

function handleSliderSlide(e, ui)
{
  var maxScroll = $("#content-scroll").attr("scrollHeight") - $
("#content-scroll").height();
  $("#content-scroll").attr({scrollTop: ui.value * (maxScroll /
100) }); 
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
  <script src="jquery-1.3.2.min.js" language="javascript" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="jquery-ui-1.7.1.custom.min.js" language="javascript" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="slider_test.js" language="javascript" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <style>
    #main {
      width: 510px;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }

    #content-slider {
      width:4px;
      height:510px;
      margin: 5px;float:left;
      background: #BBBBBB;

    }

    .ui-slider-handle {
      float:left;
      height:10px;width:10px;
      background-color:#03F;
 }

    #content-scroll {
      width: 500px;
      height: 500px;
      margin-top: 10px;
      overflow: hidden;
      border: solid 1px black;
   float:left;
    }

    #content-holder {
      width: 800px;
      height: 270px;
    }

    .content-item {
      width: 490px;
      height: 270px;
      padding: 5px;
      float: left;
   margin:auto 0 0 100px;
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="content-slider"></div>
<div id="content-scroll">
  <div id="content-holder">
    <div class="content-item">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ut turpis sagittis, nec placerat, molestie convallis. Mattis et delectus, nullam cras et, faucibus ultrices. Nunc elit, tellus vulputate eros. Leo wisi, luctus pretium. Platea arcu, in natoque non, ipsum eu vivamus.</p>
      <p>Justo dictumst, aliquam metus. Libero sed vivamus, cursus felis etiam. Eu nonummy vestibulum, class excepturi. Nulla tincidunt urna. Phasellus ac lacus, sit eu massa. Velit pretium purus. Rem ac porta.</p>
       <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ut turpis sagittis, nec placerat, molestie convallis. Mattis et delectus, nullam cras et, faucibus ultrices. Nunc elit, tellus vulputate eros. Leo wisi, luctus pretium. Platea arcu, in natoque non, ipsum eu vivamus.</p>
      <p>Justo dictumst, aliquam metus. Libero sed vivamus, cursus felis etiam. Eu nonummy vestibulum, class excepturi. Nulla tincidunt urna. Phasellus ac lacus, sit eu massa. Velit pretium purus. Rem ac porta.</p>
       <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ut turpis sagittis, nec placerat, molestie convallis. Mattis et delectus, nullam cras et, faucibus ultrices. Nunc elit, tellus vulputate eros. Leo wisi, luctus pretium. Platea arcu, in natoque non, ipsum eu vivamus.</p>
      <p>Justo dictumst, aliquam metus. Libero sed vivamus, cursus felis etiam. Eu nonummy vestibulum, class excepturi. Nulla tincidunt urna. Phasellus ac lacus, sit eu massa. Velit pretium purus. Rem ac porta.</p>
       <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ut turpis sagittis, nec placerat, molestie convallis. Mattis et delectus, nullam cras et, faucibus ultrices. Nunc elit, tellus vulputate eros. Leo wisi, luctus pretium. Platea arcu, in natoque non, ipsum eu vivamus.</p>
      <p>Justo dictumst, aliquam metus. Libero sed vivamus, cursus felis etiam. Eu nonummy vestibulum, class excepturi. Nulla tincidunt urna. Phasellus ac lacus, sit eu massa. Velit pretium purus. Rem ac porta.</p>
       <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ut turpis sagittis, nec placerat, molestie convallis. Mattis et delectus, nullam cras et, faucibus ultrices. Nunc elit, tellus vulputate eros. Leo wisi, luctus pretium. Platea arcu, in natoque non, ipsum eu vivamus.</p>
      <p>Justo dictumst, aliquam metus. Libero sed vivamus, cursus felis etiam. Eu nonummy vestibulum, class excepturi. Nulla tincidunt urna. Phasellus ac lacus, sit eu massa. Velit pretium purus. Rem ac porta.</p>
       <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ut turpis sagittis, nec placerat, molestie convallis. Mattis et delectus, nullam cras et, faucibus ultrices. Nunc elit, tellus vulputate eros. Leo wisi, luctus pretium. Platea arcu, in natoque non, ipsum eu vivamus.</p>
      <p>Justo dictumst, aliquam metus. Libero sed vivamus, cursus felis etiam. Eu nonummy vestibulum, class excepturi. Nulla tincidunt urna. Phasellus ac lacus, sit eu massa. Velit pretium purus. Rem ac porta.</p>
    </div>
    </div>


  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#content-slider").slider({
        animate: true,
            orientation: "vertical",
            value: 0,
            range: "max", 
            min: -100, 
            max: 0, 
        change: handleSliderChange,
        slide: handleSliderSlide
      });

    });

    function handleSliderChange(e, ui)
    {
      var maxScroll = $("#content-scroll").attr("scrollHeight") - $
    ("#content-scroll").height();
      $("#content-scroll").animate({scrollTop: ui.value * (maxScroll /
    -100) }, 1000);

    }

    function handleSliderSlide(e, ui)
    {
      var maxScroll = $("#content-scroll").attr("scrollHeight") - $
    ("#content-scroll").height();
      $("#content-scroll").attr({scrollTop: ui.value * (maxScroll /
    -100) }); 
    }
```